# Android Bottom Navigation Bar in activities

Tags: android

I am developing a car rental app and right now I have 3 fragments in my app (Home - where all the cars are displayed from a recyclerview , Orders - where user's bookings are shown , Profile - user profile). I can switch beetween these 3 fragments from my bottom navigationbar.

Now I created onclick listeners for every car on home page. When I click on a car it sends me to a new activity "activity_car_detail.xml" which contains specific information about the selected car. My question is: how can I make the navigation bar to appear on this Car Detail activity? Should I use fragment instead of activity or what should I do?

This is the code for the Main Activity which contains the bottom navigation bar:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static ProgressBar progressBar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new HomeFragment()).commit();
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Fragment selectedFragment = null;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_orders:
                selectedFragment = new OrdersFragment();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                selectedFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                break;
        }


        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();

        return true;
    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the Navigation component instead of Fragment transactions. Also this will fix your issue and it will remove boilerplate code. Read more about it's documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started).